# Dismissing presented view controller won't work

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a kind of complicated modal segue setup in my project. I'm trying to dismiss a view controller another view controller previously presented. I'm doing so with this code:

```
if(self.presentedViewController != nil){
    print(self.presentedViewController!)
    self.presentedViewController!.dismiss(animated: false)
    print(self.presentedViewController!)
}
```

The `print`s are there for debugging purposes. They show that the presentedViewController doesn't actually get closed.
Even though I've set `animated` to false, I still see an animation occuring in the app when dismiss is called. Yet, the VC doesn't actually get dismissed.
Anyone knows a solution?

Comment: You might want to post a picture of your storyboard.

Comment: A better way to check if a view controller has been deinitialized is  `deinit { print("great success") }`

Comment: As sconewolf correctly reminded me, if you want to dismiss the presented view controller, just do `dismiss(animated: false)`, not `presentedViewController!.dismiss(animated: false)`. The latter will, if the presented VC has itself presented other VCs, will only dismiss the ones it presented. By calling `dismiss` on the presenting VC alone, that will dismiss whatever it presented (and its children, too).

Answer (score 13):

**Apple**

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view
>   controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view
>   controller itself, UIKit asks the presenting view controller to handle
>   the dismissal.
>
> dismiss(animated:completion:) dismisses the view controller that was
>   presented modally by the view controller.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss

If you present a view controller from the app's root, for example:

**Presenting view controller**

```
let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
root.present(someViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You would dismiss it from the presented view controller like so:

**Presented view controller**

```
let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
root?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: And calling `root?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` does not dismiss the root view controller, it dismisses the view controller that was presented modally by that view controller. That is what `dismiss(animated:completion:)` does.

Comment: Absolutely right. I stand corrected. I've always called it from the presented view controller (which, as you point out, asks the presenting view controller to handle the dismissal).

Comment: I got this compiler error "'shared' is unavailable in application extensions for iOS: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead."
Using UIApplication.shared is deprecated in extension